# Can mod_rewrite be used to hide an entire /directory/ in a url?

Tags: redirect, mod-rewrite

Let's say my site is located at:

```
domain.com/directory/index.html
```

I also have pages at:

```
domain.com/directory/page1234.html
domain.com/directory/mydir/page4321.html
```

I want it to appear as domain.com/index.html and

```
domain.com/page1234.html
domain.com/mydir/page4321.html
```

Could I use mod_rewrite to hide the /directory/ and if so, is this an ideal solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mod_rewrite` is helpful only if users are making requests for `http://domain.com/directory/*` and you want them to be redirected to `http://domain.com/*`. If you don't want `directory/` showing in URLs at all, anywhere, you'll need to do something else.

If all your pages are under `directory` (i.e. the actual filesystem path is `/var/www/directory`) the ideal solution is to set your `DocumentRoot` to be `/var/www/directory` instead of `/var/www`.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. So how do I change the DocumentRoot? Is that in htaccess?

Comment: The DocumentRoot directive should be in the configuration file that defines the site in Apache. If you're on shared hosting you may need to use your control panel to tweak it; if you have a VPS you'll want to tweak the Apache configuration. Where that is varies a bit depending on your version of Apache and your OS.